Federal Tax Credits for Energy Efficiency
Hello does anybody know if I can get both water heater and HVAC tax credit, $2,000 each, if I upgrade both to a heatpump version this year?
https://www.energystar.gov/about/federal-tax-credits#savings
https://www.energystar.gov/about/federal-tax-credits/air-source-heat-pumps
https://www.energystar.gov/about/federal-tax-credits/heat-pump-water-heaters

You can try asking here: https://energystar.my.site.com/ENERGYSTAR/s/contactsupport Maybe they can give you a definitive answer.

I believe the answer is that they are independent and you can claim both. But definitely contact the folks who run the program, and/or your local utility companies, for an official answer and (if in doubt) to confirm that your planned installation will qualify.

I’m voting to close this question because it is about tax accounting and not home improvement.

@RMDman While it is technically about tax accounting, I just read through the IRS document linked in the answer, and this actually provides extremely useful information for someone considering potentially qualifying home improvements.

@mkatz,  While there is good information to be aware of, unless someone posting an answer here is a tax accountant, it would not be prudent to give tax advice on a home improvement forum. the information can change yearly and with other qualifying circumstances.  This is why we don't allow pricing advice.

You can only claim the $2000 once per year.
You can deduct up to $2000 per year total for the heat pump credit (so you'll max out the credit if you spend $6666 or more on heat pump systems in one year). It doesn't matter if this is one of the two systems or both systems at once, the cap is still $2000 total, and you can't roll over excess into future years.
Separately, you can deduct up to $1200 per year total for the other energy efficiency improvements listed. So if you do a combination of heat pump and other upgrades, you can claim up to $3200.
So to maximize your tax credits, you'll want to split up your upgrades across multiple tax years.
Source: IRS fact sheet FS-2022-40. I recommend reading though it, there's plenty of examples and frequently asked questions covered.
